# How to trigger an action from a custom button in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I've created a subclass of `UIButton` to allow me to have a checkbox on the iPhone. This checkbox is part of a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. My question is how I can attach an action to the button being pressed and have that method implemented in the table view controller?

I tried using the `addTarget:action:` method but this doesn't seem to work. One option is to use the App Delegate but this isn't good programming practice.

Comment: What did you put as the Target? Did you add an event to trigger the action (e.g. touchup inside, or connect via IBOutlet)?

Comment: First, when you say the checkbox is part of a subclass of UITableViewCell, what do you mean? How are you adding it? Second, what do you mean by `addTarget:action:` "doesn't seem to work." I assume you mean `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` here. Which controlEvents are you passing? A small amount of code, and some details about "doesn't work" would be helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did implemented the same functionality. Here is how I implemented it.

1. Created a custom cell.
2. Implement button action in cell class only.
3. Declare a protocol(CustomCellDelegate) in cell & create a delegate(CustomCellDelegate) property ofcell.
4. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view controller set table view controller(self) to delegate property of cell.
5. Implement delegates in view controller.
6. Call delegate methods from button action method in cell.

Let me know whether you understood it or I need to post some code.

Comment: Worked for me :) Thanks! (Too bad I can't set your answer as the correct one)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button receives the touch event. You could check this by overriding

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

or

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Log something or set a breakpoint on either of those. If your button is not receiving touches (which I think it doesn't) try setting `exclusiveTouch` on the TableView and/or the TableViewCell to NO.

Comment: It does take touches though. It's a bit odd.